# Passing a Prop in an On Click Function in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, onclick, action, redux

I have an `onClick` function that calls an action creator called `toggleButton` which changes the state of `this.props.UserOpen`. The following code WORKS and sets the prop `UserOpen` to true.

```
class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.props.toggleButton.bind(this, true)}>Click Me!</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { UserOpen: state.UserOpen };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({toggleButton}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonComponent);
```

Here's the offending Code which I want to incorporate.

```
 <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.props.toggleButton.bind(this, {!this.props.UserOpen})}>Click Me!</a>
```

When `onClick` is called, I want to toggle the UserOpen prop in the `toggleButton` parameter between `true` and `false`. Is this possible or do I have to make a separate function to call the action creator?

EDIT-- more code

actions.js

```
export function toggleButton(status){
  return {
    type: BUTTON_OPEN,
    payload: status
 };
```

}

reducer.js

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { buttonOpen:true};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BUTTON_OPEN:
        return {...state, buttonOpen: action.payload};
  }
  return state;
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice to change props directly, You should always change and update state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's all about toggling a boolean value of a state property, than you can easily do it in the reducer:

```
case SOME_TYPE: {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    UserOpen: !state.UserOpen
  })      
}
```

In this case your action creator should have just the `type` property:

```
function toggleButton() {
  return {
    type: SOME_TYPE
  }
}
```

If you insist to pass a property from the component, you can do something  like this:

```
class ButtonComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    this.toggleButton = this.props.toggleButton.bind(this)
    return (
      <div>
        <a href="javascript:;" onClick={function() { this.toggleButton(!this.props.UserOpen) }}> Click Me!</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best approach, I updated my code above with my action creator and reducer, if I do it via the reducer, do I need to pass a payload via my action creator?

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.toggleButton(this)}>Click Me!</a>
```

It's a good idea to not bind values in the render method where possible and also just for the sake of readability how about something like:

```
toggleButton = () => {
  this.props.toggleButton(!this.props.userOpen)
} 

render() {
  return (
    <div >
      <a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.toggleButton}>Click Me!</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: tried that one but it did not work without binding 'this' to button functon

Comment: @metamorph_online Added the new bind syntax for methods alternatively can bind it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the component's props, unless it is array or object. If you really want to change the props, than you can wrap it into an object and use the value instead.
UserOpen will be an object containing `value` inside it.

`<a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.props.toggleButton.bind(this, {!this.props.UserOpen.value})}>Click Me!</a>`

However, updating the state instead of props is the best practice.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `toggleButton` is an action creator that will dispatch  an action and mutate the state in the reducer. All @lost9123193 wants, is to pass a param to it.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, it's not about changing the prop, it's about updating the state.